# laravel change nullable column to no nullable in foreign key

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, migration, laravel-5.3

This is my migration:

```
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('nombre1',255);
        $table->string('nombre2',255)->nullable();
        $table->string('apellido1',255)->nullable();
        $table->string('apellido2',255)->nullable();
        $table->string('apellido_casada',255)->nullable();
        $table->string('cedula',255)->nullable();
        $table->integer('entidad_id')->nulleable()->unsigned();
        **$table->integer('cargo_id')->nulleable()->unsigned();
        $table->integer('partido_id')->nulleable()->unsigned();
        $table->integer('provincia_id')->nulleable()->unsigned();
        $table->integer('distrito_id')->nulleable()->unsigned();
        $table->integer('corregimiento_id')->nulleable()->unsigned();**
        $table->string('otro_nombre',255)->nullable();
        $table->dateTime('fecha_nacimiento')->nullable();
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->softDeletes();
        $table->foreign('entidad_id')->references('id')->on('entidad');
        $table->foreign('cargo_id')->references('id')->on('cargo');
        $table->foreign('partido_id')->references('id')->on('partido');
        $table->foreign('provincia_id')->references('id')->on('provincia');
        $table->foreign('distrito_id')->references('id')->on('distrito');
        $table->foreign('corregimiento_id')->references('id')->on('corregimiento');
```

When i run this migration the table generated is:

```
    CREATE TABLE pep (
    id INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    nombre1 VARCHAR(255) COLLATE UTF8_UNICODE_CI NOT NULL,
    nombre2 VARCHAR(255) COLLATE UTF8_UNICODE_CI DEFAULT NULL,
    apellido1 VARCHAR(255) COLLATE UTF8_UNICODE_CI DEFAULT NULL,
    apellido2 VARCHAR(255) COLLATE UTF8_UNICODE_CI DEFAULT NULL,
    apellido_casada VARCHAR(255) COLLATE UTF8_UNICODE_CI DEFAULT NULL,
    cedula VARCHAR(255) COLLATE UTF8_UNICODE_CI DEFAULT NULL,
    **entidad_id INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    cargo_id INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    partido_id INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    provincia_id INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    distrito_id INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    corregimiento_id INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,**
    otro_nombre VARCHAR(255) COLLATE UTF8_UNICODE_CI DEFAULT NULL,
    fecha_nacimiento DATETIME DEFAULT NULL,
    created_at TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    updated_at TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    deleted_at TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id),
    KEY pep_entidad_id_foreign (entidad_id),
    KEY pep_cargo_id_foreign (cargo_id),
    KEY pep_partido_id_foreign (partido_id),
    KEY pep_provincia_id_foreign (provincia_id),
    KEY pep_distrito_id_foreign (distrito_id),
    KEY pep_corregimiento_id_foreign (corregimiento_id),
    CONSTRAINT pep_cargo_id_foreign FOREIGN KEY (cargo_id)
        REFERENCES cargo (id),
    CONSTRAINT pep_corregimiento_id_foreign FOREIGN KEY (corregimiento_id)
        REFERENCES corregimiento (id),
    CONSTRAINT pep_distrito_id_foreign FOREIGN KEY (distrito_id)
        REFERENCES distrito (id),
    CONSTRAINT pep_entidad_id_foreign FOREIGN KEY (entidad_id)
        REFERENCES entidad (id),
    CONSTRAINT pep_partido_id_foreign FOREIGN KEY (partido_id)
        REFERENCES partido (id),
    CONSTRAINT pep_provincia_id_foreign FOREIGN KEY (provincia_id)
        REFERENCES provincia (id)
)  ENGINE=INNODB DEFAULT CHARSET=UTF8 COLLATE = UTF8_UNICODE_CI;
```

The problem is that some of the columns:  entidad_id, cargo_id, etc, are declared as NULL and when i set the FK, laravel created them as NOT NULL.

Is anyting here that i am missing??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry for being late.

You have typos in code

`nulleable`

`$table->integer('entidad_id')->nulleable()->unsigned();`

should be

`nullable`

`$table->integer('entidad_id')->nullable()->unsigned();`

Don't know why Laravel is not yelling on typos :(